# Did Draupadī had a mother.?

Tags: mahabharata, marriage, draupadi, children, mother

Draupadī was born from fire. Did she had a mother.?
Wiki tells that Draupada had a wife.

But, did Draupadī had a mother.? Was Draupada's wife alive when she emerged from the fire.?

Was there any contribution of the Draupada's wife in Draupadī's birth.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Drupada had a wife, who was named Pr̥ṣati. She was alive during the time Draupadī was born. The story from Ādiparva went like this.

After pouring libations of ghī in the *havana*(oblation), Yāja, who was the head priest conducting the *havana*, told the queen that 'a son and daughter have appeared' and invited her to eat the *havis* (ritual offering). The queen entreated that her mouth was still filled with saffron and other perfumed things, and her body was also bearing many scents, which made her unfit to accept the *havis*. So, she pleaded with Yāja to wait for her to wash herself and return.

Yāja replied, that whether she come now or later, why should the object of sacrifice wait when the *havana* is already prepared by him and sanctified by the invocations of Upayāja (brother of Yāja). In line with his view, Yāja refused to wait and put the *havis* into the ritual fire. And thus, from the fire sprang Dhr̥ṣṭadyumna and Draupadī.

Beholding the brilliant children, Pr̥ṣati personally requested Yāja that the children must accept her(and no one else) as their mother. And Yāja granted that request on account of Drupada.

So, Drupada and Pr̥ṣati were the parents of Draupadī and Dhr̥ṣṭadyumna, regardless of the fact that they weren't their biological children.

**Reference**

Section CLXIX, Caitraratha Parva, Ādi Parva, Mahābhārata (trans. Kisari Mohan Ganguli) https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc4166.html